# What creature has spokes in its eyes, a beak, and strands of hair coming from the very tip of its triangular ears?

Tags: character-identification

On the ski trips to France last year and this year, I saw shops selling **decorative caps to be worn on a ski helmet**.  These caps depict the head of a variety of creatures, and are made of some soft textile material with eyes, ears and snouts sewn on them.  (I sincerely hope this great invention might encourage some adults to wear ski helmets who would otherwise be reluctant to.)

Some of the creatures depicted by the caps are real world animals (although not in a realistic manner): rooster (which are considered a symbol for France), piglet, wolf, panda.  One cap apparently depicts the green pig character from the Angry Birds video game.  But some caps are definitely depicting characters from Science Fiction & Fantasy works: Spiderman and Pikachu (Pokémon).

The two photos below depict some of these caps.  Follow the links higher resolution images.

But there is one cap that I can't identify.  This shows **a creature with spokes in its round eyes, what appears to be a beak, and strands of hair coming from the very tip of its triangular ears**.  You can see it on the first picture below.  What is this creature?

I can't tell for sure whether that creature is from a Science Fiction or Fantasy work.  If it turns out not to be, then this question would be off-topic.  I'm simply interpolating from the other Fantasy creatures seen, given that I don't recognize this as a real world creature.

[image: Helmet caps image 0]

[Helmet caps image 0 (see higher resolution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAeEX.jpg)

[image: Helmet caps image 0]

[Helmet caps image 1 (see higher resolution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngVtI.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The company's [online catalogue](http://www.creations-dani.fr/catalogues/montagne/) (p47) merely identifies it as "Owl", part of a wider range of animal hats. Several appear to be generically similar to famous brands, whereas others do not.

[image]

It also seems to come in blue, but only when you buy it in a presentation stand

[image]

Comment: Actually, the price given on the site is €5.95 **HT** (_hors taxes_ = excluding 20% VAT). The **TTC** (_toutes taxes comprises_ = including VAT) price would be around €7, and that's still on the manufacturer’s website. In a retail shop, particularly at a ski resort, it would quite naturally be more expensive. I'd say anything less than €10 would be all right in a ski resort shop. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I was looking at the price when you buy the presentation stand :-) That being said, my limited grasp of French would suggest that the RRP is €14.95

Comment: Is that in the catalogue? That does seem like a bit of a ripoff as RRP’s go. (For some reason, when I try to open the link, it just gives me a blank, white page, so I only have your screen shot to go by.)